# How to autostart BitTorrent Sync on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-13.04, bittorrent-sync

I am trying to get my BT Sync application to auto start when I turn on my computer, which is what is does under Windows but I have now moved over the Ubuntu 13.04, which is a very good O/S.

Now I have tried the 'Startup Applications' and added the BT Sync executable file into a new entry, however when I go to load the Web GUI, I find that BT Sync has not started, if I load it from the terminal, it will fork to desktop or states something like that, and then works.

I have also found the following guide:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/05/heres-how-to-automatically-startup-programs-for-all-users-using-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

What I would love to know is it safe to do what this guide is laying out, becuase there is no .desktop file for this application, so do I just make one? I have seem a number of guides on how to do this, so it should not be a big issue.

One last thing the BT Sync file does not end in .sh or anything, is that normal for applications? I always thought that they had to end in a file that the system could load or have I just installed it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to /etc/rc.local before exit 0

./path_to_btsync/btsync --config /path_to_config/btsync.conf

Answer (score 0):

I found adding: `service btsync start` to `/etc/rc.local` to be effective also.